What are the medical properties/breakdowns of the drug "celebret"? Does it come close to anything based off the real world, etc?
I've always wondered. What's it based off of? Or maybe off multiple compounds?

Cross-posted from Reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/gangsta/comments/1345epe/what_is_the_medical_propertiesbreakdowns_of_the/
